# Android Compose, Viewmodel and Data layer with Services

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-service, android-viewmodel

I am starting with Android developing and I am struggling with Compose and `Viewmodel`.

In order to get some knowledge I have followed this tutorial to get the basics regarding UI interaction with my app data through `ViewModel` and data layer:
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-viewmodel-and-state#0

For a basic app it is ok, now I have to adapt this tutorial to my needs which are: An app that will start on user request (UI button) a foreground service which will record audio in the background (even if the app is closed) and the recording status and events (given by the service) should be shown in the UI. The service part is already working so I need some support regarding the UI interaction.

So my questions:

1. Where is the right place to start the service? In `MainActivity`? in `ViewModel` (Viewmodel lacks of context to start the service)?
2. Once the service is started how to update the UI based on the events generated inside the service (based on the audio recorded)? I was thinking on implementing `LocalBroadcastManager` and listen in my `ViewModel` implementation for events generated in the service, but I see that `LocalBroadcastManageris` deprecated.

This is my code for the ViewModel and data layer:

```
class ServiceView(): ViewModel() {
    data class ServiceViewData(
        var isStarted:Boolean = false,
        var isCapturing:Boolean = false,
        var isPlaying:Boolean = false,
        var isAutoPlaying:Boolean = false,
    )
    var serviceViewData by mutableStateOf(ServiceViewData())

    fun startService(){
        // Start the service here?
        serviceViewData = serviceViewData.copy(isStarted = true)
    }
}
```

Regarding the UI it will be composed based on the values from my `ServiceViewData` data layer defined in my `ServiceView` `ViewModel`, so the events from my service should be somehow received in the `ViewModel` in order to modify my `ServiceViewData`.

Any help?

Comment: Have you reviewed the documentation on Services, in particular _bound_ Services? https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/services/bound-services

Comment: Thanks for the link, it explains how to use the Messenger for the bidirectional communication and all the examples in that page show that the service is being created from the Activity. The only problem is that in the examples they are not using Jetpack Compose so for me is not still clear how to link the service and my ViewModel implementation

Comment: Using Compose should be irrelevant - that's a UI abstraction. You're working a layer below that - business logic that determines what the UI _state_ should be. I've expanded in an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

At a high-level, you could have an interface (or flow) that your Service uses for pushing events, which your Activity would use to act as a mediator between the Service and ViewModel. Your activity also observes the VM as usual and updates the UI, be it Compose or Views.

Activity -> observes -> Service -> then updates -> ViewModel 
Activity -> observes -> ViewModel -> then updates -> UI

So your Service could look something like:

```
class YourService : Service {
    data class ServiceEventParams(...)

    interface EventListener {
        fun onSomeServiceEvent()
    }

    val eventListener: EventListener? = null // Or a flow of params

    fun functionThatWantsToPropogateEvents() {
        // DO STUFF then notify any listener that stuff happened
        val params = ServiceEventParams(...)
        eventListener?.onSomeServiceEvent(params)
    }
}
```

Using the sample from [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/services/bound-services#Binder), your Activity it might look like this:

```
class BindingActivity : Activity() {
    private lateinit var mService: LocalService
    private var mBound: Boolean = false

    private val mViewModel = getViewModelSomehow() // <- NEW

    // NEW - listener for service events
    private val mServiceEventListener = object : YourService.EventListener {
        override fun onSomeServiceEvent(params: ServiceEventParams) {
            mViewModel.doSomethingToRespondToServiceEvent(params)
        }
    }
    
    /** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService().  */
    private val connection = object : ServiceConnection {

        override fun onServiceConnected(className: ComponentName, service: IBinder) {
            // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance.
            val binder = service as LocalService.LocalBinder
            mService = binder.getService()
            mBound = true

            // NEW - register listener on the service to get callbacks
            mService.eventListener = mServiceEventListener
            // OR Collect a flow of events
        }

        override fun onServiceDisconnected(arg0: ComponentName) {
            mBound = false

            // NEW - clear out listener on the service to stop callbacks
            mService.eventListener = null
            // OR stop collecting a flow of events
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // NEW - initialize UI and observe ViewModel to update UI state
        // whether it's Compose or Views
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        // Bind to LocalService.
        Intent(this, LocalService::class.java).also { intent ->
            bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
        }
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        unbindService(connection)
        mBound = false
    }
}
```

Finally, your viewmodel just needs to handle the service params and convert to view state:

```
class ServiceViewModel : ViewModel {
    fun doSomethingToRespondToServiceEvent(params: ServiceEventParams) {
        serviceViewData = someFunctionThatMapsToViewState(params)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, is very enlightening. The only issue I have with your code, is in the call to "mService.setListener" inside "onServiceConnected" overrided function. I assume that I have to define this "onServiceConnected" function in my service but I do not know which code should I implement in that function in order to "set the listener"

Comment: "I assume that I have to define this "onServiceConnected" function in my service" - no. Review the code carefully. `onServiceConnected` is a member of `ServiceConnection`, an instance of which is declared inline as a member of the Activity.

Comment: I am sorry but I had a mistake in my comment, I wanted to say: "I assume that I have to define this "setListener" function in my service"

Comment: Yes. That is `val eventListener: EventListener? = null // Or a flow of params`. A kotlin property can be invoked via "get" / "set" for java interop. I updated my answer to replace "set" with direct property use for clarity.